# jQuery newbie: how to update radio buttons values in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a group of radio buttons on my page:

```
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" checked> apple
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange"> orange
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana"> banana
```

If I want to update the **appearance value** of the radio buttons dynamically, how to do it in jQuery (or what is the best way to do it in jQuery)? I am using jQuery 1.5.1

I mean for example, update the values from :

"**apple**", "**orange**" and "**banana**"

to

"**watermelon**", "**pear**" and "**strawberry**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to add value attributes to each of the radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" checked> apple
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange"> orange
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana"> banana
```

you can then use jquery to update the values with

```
$("input[value='apple']").val("Melon");
```

Ideally you would want to add a unique identifier to each of the radio buttons for example

```
<input id="option1" type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" checked="checked"> <label for="option1">apple</label>
<input id="option2" type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" checked="checked"> <label for="option2">orange</label>
<input id="option3" type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" checked="checked"> <label for="option3">banana</label>
```

By adding an id to each of the radio buttons allows you to do the following:

```
$("#option1").val("Melon"); //This will update the radio button value
$("label[for='option1']").html("Melon"); //This will update the label value
```

Also by wrapping the labels in label tags makes them clickable to select the associated radio button

Comment: Hi, the label is not updated by using your code, only the radio button value updated.

Comment: @ Leo, right, now it works. could you please update your post also, so that other people wont have the same problem, then I will accept your answer. Thank you.